# Labview: Extract Digit Values from This String

Tags: extract, labview

This should be quite simple for the experts.

How do I extract the value 2.11 from this string !IR1= -2.11:24
OR
extracting 3.27 from this strong !IR1= 3.27:88

Thank you!

Regards,
Prof

Answer (score 3):

[image: VI snippet showing scan from string]

This shows how to use Scan From String to get at the value you want. Note that there's a space between the open square bracket and the hyphen. This matches any number of spaces and/or hyphens between the text `!IR1=` and the numeric value.

This image is a VI snippet so you should be able to drag it right on to your LabVIEW diagram and use the code.

If you right-click on Scan From String and choose 'Edit Scan String' you get this dialogue:

[image: screenshot of Edit Scan String window]

which helps you to assemble the scan string you want. Note that it puts spaces in between each of the scan items by default, which you may not want. To get more help on constructing scan strings, see the LabVIEW help for Scan From String.

Answer (score 3):

When scanning a Real number I always recommend to explicitly specify the *decimal separator character* in the *format string*.

Using the vi **Programming/String/Scan From String** you should use a format string like `%.;!IR1= %f`.

String `%.;` at the beginning of the *format string* tells LabVIEW that your *decimal separator* is a dot (`.`), independently from *Format settings* of your OS or in LabVIEW.

Not specifying this *decimal separator* is a common mistake that could lead to unexpected results if you plan to use your code in several computers.

Comment: Although the scan string you've shown will treat the hyphen character as a minus sign and return a negative value for %f - reading the question carefully it looks as if the hyphen should be ignored and the number returned should always be positive.

Comment: @nekomatic this kind of processing (absolute value) should not be executed as a part of the _parsing function_. This lose of information makes the parsing code application specific.
I intentionally added the parsing of the sign, so if this solution is implemented _without thinking_ it will produce the less bug-wise results.